# How can you crop an SVG Image in Python?

Tags: python, svg, python-imaging-library, pycairo

With a program, I am producing an SVG image with dimensions of 400px x 400px. However, I would like to crop the bottom of this SVG image off, based off of a variable that dictates how much of the bottom of the image should be cropped in pixels.

This SVG image is being generated with pyCairo with `surface = cairo.SVGSurface("output.svg", WIDTH, HEIGHT)` and `ctx = cairo.Context(surface)`.

Although the `HEIGHT` variable is a constant and isn't changed, after I perform some operations on the `surface` object, I would like to be able to resize it once more. I can use the Pillow `Image` object to crop PNGs, but it does not support SVGs.

I have also tried to open the svg file with `open("output.svg")`. However, if I try to read it, I am unable to and it shows up as blank, thus making it unmodifiable.

Is there any way in Python to either crop an SVG image or modify its size after it has been modified with pycairo?

Answer (score 2):

The answer above is incomplete and at least for me doesn't solve the problem.

A SVG can simply be cropped (trimmed, clipped, cut) using [vpype](https://vpype.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#trim) with the crop or trim and translate commands.

```
import vpype_cli as vp
#vp.excute("read test.svg translate 300 400 trim 30 20 write output.svg")
vpype_cli.execute("read test.svg crop 0cm 0cm 10cm 20cm write output.svg")
```

Playing around with the parameters should lead to the desired crop.

Took some time to find this, as most answers say it cant be done, which is ridiculous.

Comment: It should be said that vypype while awesome does not support full svg spec, and will mangle the original svg in some cases, for example convert smooth paths into series of straight lines (poly lines) and may screw up gradients and effects etc.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot crop SVG like you crop PNG because in the latter you can just drop pixels, while for the former you have defined paths that can't be easily recomputed.

If you're sure there's nothing in the part you are about to "crop", you can use `set_context_size` to make the svg context/canvas smaller while preserving ratio and size inside.

Comment: In the documentation, I cannot find any `set_context_size` command and can't figure out how to use it. Could you please elaborate and give me an example of how to use the `set_context_size()` command?

Comment: I have tried running both `ctx.set_context_size()` and `surface.set_context_size()` and both throw `AttributeErrors` as they cannot be found.